# Custom templates with model_utils.Choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model with CharField using model_utils.Choices:

```
from model_utils import Choices

class UserTestStatistics(models.Model):
TEST_STATUSES = Choices(
    ('NR', 'not_readed'),('NP', 'not_passed'),
    ('FL', 'failed'), ('PD', 'passed'),        
)
status = models.CharField(choices=TEST_STATUSES, max_length=2)
```

In template I want to add custom css class depending on value in status field. I tried this:

```
{% if lecture.status == 'NP' %}
    label-warning
{% endif %}
```

This didn'work. Then I tried this:

```
context['statuses'] = UserTestStatistics.TEST_STATUSES

{% elif lecture.status == statuses.not_passed %}
    label-warning
{% endif %}
```

And it failed too. And here is why:

```
>>> s = UserTestStatistics.objects.get(lecture=l)
>>> type(s.status)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> type(UserTestStatistics.TEST_STATUSES.passed)
<type 'str'>
```

Quick-and-dirty solution is to add custom template tag that will convert both to uncode and then compare, but for me it looks like I'm wrong somwhere.

Can anyone please advise something more pretty?

Comment: I'd have expected the first thing you tried to work. What was the output from `{{ lecture.status }}`?

Comment: you forgot to put unicode in your model

Comment: Funny thing: I've been thinking about that for several days, but found  where I was wrong in couple of minutes after I published question. Unicode method has nothing common with the problem, its just different model. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rather prefer the approach of having a property and not using hard coded strings over the templates.

```
@property
def is_not_readed(self):
    return self.status == UserTestStatistics.TEST_STATUSES.STATUS.NR
```

So, in your template:

```
{% if lecture.is_not_readed %}
    label-warning
{% endif %}
```

Alternatively you could have the TEST_STATUSES as

```
Choices('draft', 'published')
class UserTestStatistics(models.Model):
    TEST_STATUSES = Choices('not_readed', 'not_passed', 'failed', 'passed')
...
```

So, in the template:

```
{% if lecture.status = lecture.TEST_STATUSES.not_readed %}
    label-warning
{% endif %}
```

Remember, having magic 'Strings' over the template isn't that good thinking in terms of refactoring and legibility.

I hope this can help some one.
Or if you have a different idea/approach, let everyone know it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.status
```